# Trouble with Heine-Borel Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

According to the Heine-Borel Theorem: A subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

I'm having trouble with the converse that $E$ being closed and bounded implies that it is compact.

Consider the set $E$ of single points on the real line on the interval $(0, 1)$ that start at $\frac{1}{2}$ and get infinitely close to both $0$ and $1$ (edit: As in $E = \{a_n\}$ where $a_1 = 1/2$, $a_2 = 1/3$, $a_3 = 1 - 1/3$, $a_4 = 1/4$, $a_5 = 1- 1/4$, etc). This set would be a closed set, since the union of any number of open sets is an open set and the set $E$ can be defined as the complement of the union of open intervals between adjacent points in $E$ as well as the open sets $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(1, \infty)$. The family of sets defined as the union of balls of very small radius (so that they don't overlap) around each of the points in $E$ is an open cover for E but does not have a finite subcover of $E$.

Can someone explain why this isn't true?

Comment: What do you mean by "that starts at $\frac{1}{2}$ and get infinitely close to both $0$ and $1$"? This *dynamic* description seems not properly translated to a static, set-theoretic language.

Comment: As in the set {a_n} where a_1 = 1/2, a_2 = 1/3, a_3 = 1 - 1/3, a_4 = 1/4, a_5 = 1- 1/4, etc.

Comment: The set $$E=\{\tfrac{1}{n}, 1-\tfrac{1}{n} : n =1, 2, \ldots \}=\{\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{2}{3},\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{3}{4},\ldots\}$$ is **not closed** since it does not contain its limit points $0$ and $1$. If you consider its closure $$\overline{E} = E \cup \{0, 1\}, $$ then it is closed and bounded, hence compact. You can indeed show, using a direct argument, that every open cover of $\overline{E}$ has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is only closed in the subset topology on $(0,1)$ which is not the same as the topology on $\mathbb{R}$, so the Heine-Borel Theorem does not apply. If you consider $E$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $1 \in E^c$, but any open interval containing $1$ also has a nonempty intersection with $E$. Thus, $E^c$ is not open so $E$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is *not* closed.

Note that $1 \notin E \implies 1 \in \mathbb{R} - E$. The same applies to $0$. Therefore,

$$\mathbb{R} - E = (-\infty, 0] \cup \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} \left[ \left( \frac{1}{n + 2}, \frac{1}{n + 1} \right) \cup \left( \frac{n}{n + 1}, \frac{n + 1}{n + 2} \right) \right] \cup [1, \infty)$$

To see that $\mathbb{R} - E$ is not open, it suffices to show that no neighborhood of $0$ (or $1$) in $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in $E$.

If you want to consider $F = {\rm Cl} E$, which is $E$ along with the points $0, 1$, $F$ is closed, and it's easy to check that $F$ *is* compact. First, define $e_{n, 0} = \frac{1}{n}$ and $e_{n, 1} = \frac{n - 1}{n}$; we have that

$$F = \{ e_{n, 0} \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}+} \cup \{ e_{n, 1} \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$$

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an open cover of $F$. Since $0, 1 \in F$, there must be open $A_0, A_1 \in \mathcal{A}$ containing $0, 1$. Being open, $A_0, A_1$ contain $B (0, \delta_0), B (1, \delta_1)$ for some $\delta_0, \delta_1 > 0$. By Archimedean property, there exist $N_0, N_1 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $N_0 > \frac{1}{\delta_0}, N_1 > \frac{1}{\delta_1}$. Obviously, each point $e_{n, 0} \in B (0, \delta_0) \implies e_{n, 0} \in A_0$ for $n > N_0$ and $e_{n, 1} \in B (1, \delta_1) \implies e_{n, 1} \in A_1$ for $n > N_1$. For each $n \le N_0$ (of which there are finitely many), select an element $A_{n, 0} \in \mathcal{A}$ containing $e_{n, 0}$. For each $n \le N_1$ (again, finitely many), select an element $A_{n, 1} \in \mathcal{A}$ containing $e_{n, 1}$. The subcollection

$$A_0 \cup \left\{ A_{n, 0} \right\}_{n \le N_0} \cup \left\{ A_{n, 1} \right\}_{n \le N_1} \cup A_1 \subseteq \mathcal{A}$$

is finite and covers $F$.